# Microsoft Azure docs code using deprecated schema?

Tags: azure, jsonschema, dashboard, deprecated, azure-deployment

I am using Microsoft docs [Programmatically create Azure dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically) Pasting the dashboard example into VS Code Version: 1.74.3 (user setup)

I get a VS Code Extension (Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Tools v0.15.8) message about the schema being deprecated. I am directed to the github page [microsoft/vscode-azurearmtools](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurearmtools/wiki/Would-you-like-to-use-the-latest-schema-for-deployment-template-%22XXXX%22%3F)

However this page and deployment template files are older than the Microsoft docs. So which one is correct?

I ask this because I have an Azure Portal Dashboard deployment (programatical) issue open where my schema is being questioned [Azure CLI unable to create portal dashboards from templates #5824](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues/5824)

Answer (score 0):

From docs [Understand the structure and syntax of ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax)

"If you're using Visual Studio Code with the Azure Resource Manager tools extension, use the latest version for resource group deployments:
[https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#"](https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#%22)